# Is it possible for ldap users to revoke/renew/copy the root token in Hashicorp Vault?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I have recently started using vault and trying to integrate with one of my application to hold secrets. I have set up the LDAP authentication for my users to access vault and create/access secrets. BUT after login successfully, at the top right there is an option of `copy token` `renew token` `revoke token`.

Is it right for these users to access the root token? Is there a way to disable that feature?
I just want my users to access/create secrets that's it and nothing else.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're logged in with LDAP, then those options don't apply to the root token, they apply to the user-login-session token. All authentication with Vault uses tokens, not just the root one. Whenever someone logs in with LDAP, they will be issued a new token - that's the token that the menu refers to.

You can see this for yourself - assuming you already have a valid root token, log in with LDAP, then select `Revoke token` from that menu. Now try doing something with that root token (e.g., log in to the web UI or run a CLI command). You'll see that it still works - it has not been revoked.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't realise that the token is actually per session. You saved my day. :)